# Can't open/create my Salesforce projects with Mavensmate anymore

Tags: salesforce

I used to connect my Salesforce projects without any problem since today. 
Now everytime I want to create or open  a new project through Mavensmate. I get this error :

```
Error initializing project: client identifier invalid
```

[image]

I don't know how to solve it. I have googling without finding any solution. I thought [this](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/issues/853) could solve my issue, but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: mavens mate has not been supported for some time now. Have you tried vscode and the salesforce supported extensions? You can develop against any org and do not have to use scratch orgs

Comment: See: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270803/mavensmate-getting-error-client-identifier-invalid-while-authentication-to-sale?atw=1 Mavensmate has reached end of life now

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is related or already said but it sounds like MavensMate has finally died. Related conversation/details [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270803/mavensmate-getting-error-client-identifier-invalid-while-authentication-to-sale/270864#270864). If I knew how to build the windows version of the [MavensMate source](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop) I'd try myself but seems like there is a security issue that would have to be applied too which I don't have time for (plus possibly out of my expertise reach).

So I'm now biting the bullet and starting the move from Sublime to VS Code using a couple different articles ([here](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/getting-started/migrate-from-forcecom-ide) and [here](https://medium.com/@charlie_77818/how-to-switch-to-salesforcedx-vscode-without-anybody-noticing-e53962b16de4)). Pretty sad about this but seems no other way. If possible I'll loop back to Sublime in the future but no idea if that will be feasible or not. If anyone finds a fix for MavensMate or a new way to do SFDC work in Sublime please let us know!

Comment: Hi Chris did you find a way to work with Mavensmate and Salesforce. Is mavensmate issue fixed ?

Comment: From what I can tell no - Mavensmate is still dead. I've since moved on to VS Code for my SFDC work. I'm still not back to 100% of what I could do with Mavensmate but I'm close enough I guess. As much as I miss Mavensmate I am kind of glad something pushed me to use VS Code - it's slowly growing on me (even though Sublime Text as a text/code editor is still light years better).

Comment: Yeah, I do miss it Mavensmate. Since you are using VS code I have a question, Can you check code conflict before deploying in VS Code

Comment: Sorry @SFDC I'm not sure what you mean exactly. But FWIW my process goes: Update Apex Class in VS Code >> Then deploy Change to sandbox from VS Code >> Then run the related Apex Tests in VS Code >> Confirm all Apex Tests come back successful/green >> Code now ready to deploy to other/PROD SFDC instance.